# JSF is optimizing my <h:hiddenInput> away?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to save a hidden value to be used by jQuery..

The jsf code:

```
<h:datatable id="myTable" var="aRow>
  <h:inputHidden value="#{aRow.someValue}" id="myTrID"/>
  <h:column> ... </h:column>
  <h:column> ... </h:column>
</h:datatable>
```

When looking at the rendered page source I can't see any evidence of the `<h:inputHidden>`.

FYI, What I am trying to do is access this `<h:inputHidden>` with this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myTable tr").click(function(event){
    var tr_value = $(this).children("input[name='myTrID']").val();
    alert("Row Value = " + tr_value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you try to put the hidden value inside one of your columns?

Comment: @Matt No.. Your right, that did it :\

Comment: Ok, I added an answer ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put the hidden value inside one of your columns. Maybe the `h:inputHidden` is not allowed as a child of `h:dataTable`.

Comment: Tnx. How would you change the jQuery to get the value if it was in a `h:column` and in a `h:inputHidden`?

Answer (score 3):

There are two things:

- as [Matt Handy says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136163/jsf-is-optimizing-my-hhiddeninput-away/6136241#6136241), [dataTable](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/dataTable.html) can only have `column` children (though you can add other components as facets).
- also, the [clientId](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/10/jsf-working-with-component-identifiers.html) is likely to be of the form `...someOtherNamingContainers:myTable:n:myTrID` where `n` is the row index for the column; any parent that is a [NamingContainer](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) affects the `clientId`.